# How to order by price products in Exp:resso Store

Tags: expresso-store

I would like to order my products by price, how cat i do this?

I use:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" orderby="product:price_val"}
```

But it's not work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the Store [Search tag](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/search_tag.html) instead, which adds some custom Store options:

```
{exp:store:search channel="products" orderby="price"}
    <!-- normal channel entry template here -->
{/exp:store:search}
```